# Calculating Kendall's tau using scipy and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, statistics

I have a csv file with precipitation data per year and per weather station.  It looks like this:

```
station_id    year       Sum
 210018      1916      65.024
 210018      1917      35.941
 210018      1918      28.448
 210018      1919      68.58
 210018      1920      31.115
 215400      1916      44.958
 215400      1917      31.496
 215400      1918      38.989
 215400      1919      74.93
 215400      1920      53.5432
```

I want to return a Kendall's tau correlation and p-value based upon unique station id's. So for above I want the correlation between sum and year for station id 210018 and 215400.

The correlation for station_id 210018 would then be -.20 and a p-value of .62 and for station_id 215400 correlation would be .40 and a p-value of .33.

I am trying to use this:

```
grouped=df.groupby(['station_id'])
grouped.aggregate([tau, p_value=sp.stats.kendalltau(df.year, df.Sum)])
```

The error returned is a syntax error on the equal sign after p_value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to calculate this is to use `apply` on the `groupby` object:

```
>>> import scipy.stats as st
>>> df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x: st.kendalltau(x['year'], x['Sum']))
station_id
210018        (-0.2, 0.62420612399)
215400        (0.4, 0.327186890661)
dtype: object
```

Comment: this is much more intuitive than what I was attempting.  I am getting an attribute error with this though. 'module' object has no attribute 'kendalltau'

Comment: I see - does the traceback indicate what causes the attribute error? (perhaps some modification is needed for other versions of Pandas)

Comment: I got it to work, just overlooked a bit of the code on my part.  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out. (I just noticed I was using a different `scipy.stats` alias to you)